How can I run Flutter macros in the current project directory instead of the root directory ("/")?
I'm working on a Flutter project, and I've encountered an issue when trying to run macros from the command line. By default, these macros seem to execute in the root directory (/), which isn't what I want. I'd like them to run in the context of my current project directory instead.
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:macros/macros.dart';

macro class ExampleMacro implements ClassDeclarationsMacro {
  const ExampleMacro();

  @override
  void buildDeclarationsForClass(ClassDeclaration classDeclaration, MemberDeclarationBuilder declarationBuilder) {
    final pwd = _getCurrentDirectory();
    declarationBuilder.declareInType(
      DeclarationCode.fromParts([
        "  static const String currentDirectory = '$pwd';",
      ]),
    );
  }

  String _getCurrentDirectory() {
    try {
      final currentDirectory = Directory.current.path;
      return currentDirectory;
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
}


Is there a option to use environment variables? Platform.environment.toString()just shows me the variables of android studio and not mine.
